# Native method to pull out metadata about packages, procedures and functions?

Tags: oracle, metadata

I wish to be able to query Oracle for a list of public procedures and functions that belong to a package, something along the lines of:

`select procedure_name from all_package_procedures where package_name = :my_package_name;`

I also wish to be able to query Oracle for a list of parameters for a given procedure or function, something along the lines of:

`select parameter_name, in_or_out, parameter_type from all_function_parameters where   function_name = :my_function_name;`

Is this possible natively? If not, does anyone know of existing code to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query `USER_OBJECTS` & `USER_PROCEDURES` to get a list of all procedures & functions belonging to a particular package

```
SELECT procedure_name
FROM   user_procedures
WHERE  object_id = (SELECT object_id
                    FROM   user_objects
                    WHERE  object_name = '<YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME>'
                           AND object_type = 'PACKAGE')
```

Replace `user_objects` & `user_procedures` with `all_objects` & `all_procedures` respectively to fetch packages & procedures owned by other users.

---

> I also wish to be able to query Oracle for a list of parameters for a given procedure or function,

For this, you can query `user_arguments` or `all_arguments` to fetch parameters of on object owned by the current user & all users respectively

```
SELECT argument_name,
       data_type
FROM   user_arguments
WHERE  package_name = '<name-of-your-package-procedure-function>'
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks - I found that using `object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY'` returned no results, whereas `object_type = 'PACKAGE'` returned results. Any idea whether or not it's possible to get proc / function parameters?

Comment: @dom_watson my bad, I was testing with `PACKAGE BODY` first, it did not go well, so I put in the object_id of the `PACKAGE` but I forgot to edit that out while pasting the query here. As for the parameters, I've mentioned about all_arguments! Did you skip reading that? :) **ED**: yes, its possible to fetch procedure & function parameters, the `package_name` column name is a misnormer!

Comment: Ah yes, no idea how I missed that! Thanks for your help, solved.

Comment: the problem with all_arguments is that if your stored procedure doesn't have any arguments or a return type then I don't think it will be in the list of all_arguments meaning you might mistake the proc as  not existing

Answer (score 1):

My own answer, derived from Sathyas, for the reference of others. Here is a single query to pull out a denormalized result of all procedures and their arguments for a given package:

```
select     p.procedure_name
         , a.argument_name
         , a.data_type
         , a.defaulted
         , a.default_value
         , a.in_out
         , a.position
from       all_procedures p
inner join all_objects o
        on o.object_id = p.object_id
inner join all_arguments a
        on a.package_name = o.object_name
       and a.object_name = p.procedure_name
where      o.object_type = 'PACKAGE'
and        o.object_name = 'PACKAGE_NAME'
order by   p.procedure_name, a.position;
```